# How to disable eslint error "Expected imports instead of AMD define(). "

Tags: eslint

How to disable Eslint rule "Expected imports instead of AMD define()? " So that eslint wont report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to disable a rule is to turn it off in your configuration file (This is an example `.eslintrc.json` file):

```
{
  /* Your specific configuration */
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/no-function-return-type": 0 // Here I manually override this specific rule
    /* The rest of your rule overrides */
  }
}
```

From the official [ESLint documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules):

> - "off" or 0 - turn the rule off
> - "warn" or 1 - turn the rule on as a warning (doesn’t affect exit code)
> - "error" or 2 - turn the rule on as an error (exit code is 1 when triggered)

In your case I believe [this](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-amd.md) rule is giving you the error, so to turn it off just specify the following in your ESLint config:
`import/no-amd: 0`